# What does "turn guilt against the self" mean?

Tags: meaning

I was looking up the word "self" in the Oxford dictionary and came across an example with the word that reads "guilt can be turned against the self." Tell me please what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - It means: guilt can unfriendly affect yourself in a bad way; may lead you to be less confident, frustrated, pessimistic, irritated, worried, regretted, desperate, depressed,...etc

Comment: What is "pysomismirritated"? Other than that, this answer is really good. I am going to upvote it, but I'd like some understanding as to what that is supposed to be. Is it supposed to be **"pessimistic, irritated"**?  Let me know.

Comment: Yes it is pessimistic, thank you for informing me of this misprinted mistake. @Nick

Comment: It's fine, Bavyan. I was just trying to figure it out. I thought it might have been a word I didn't know, but I clearly saw "irritated" in it; the first part of the word, "pysomism," was difficult to figure out. I'm glad I could figure it out. Great answer.